# Ansible-playbook: directly run handler

Tags: configuration, ansible

Is there a way to directly run handler by `ansible-playbook`?

For example, i have handler `restart service` in my role and sometimes i want just trigger it directly without deploying whole app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of options answered in [a similar post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/617548/12214).  In summary:

Options for triggering a particular handler:

- Use a no-op `command` to trigger it
- Use a `debug` with `changed_when: true` to trigger it

Options for triggering all handlers:

- Run with `--force-handlers`
- Use a `meta: flush_handlers` task

Options for re-architecting:

- Use a task instead